# Implementing runtime-constant persistent "LUT"s in MATLAB functions

Tags: matlab

I am implementing (for class, so no built-ins!) a variant of the Hough Transform to detect circles in an image. I have a working product, and I get correct results. In other words, I'm done with the assignment! However, I'd like to take it one step further and try to improve the performance a little bit. Also, to forestall any inevitable responses, I know MATLAB isn't exactly the most performance-based language, and I know that the Hough transform isn't exactly performance-based either, but hear me out.

When generating the Hough accumulation space, I end up needing to draw a LOT of circles (approximately 75 for every edge pixel in the image; one for each search radius). I wrote a nifty function to do this, and it's already fairly optimized. However, I end up recalculating lots of circles of the same radius (expensive) at different locations (cheap).

An easy way for me to optimize this was precalculate a circle of each radius centered at zero once, and just select the proper circle and shift it into the correct position. This was easy, and it works great!

The trouble comes when trying to access this lookup table of circles.

I initially made it a persistent variable, as follows:

```
[x_subs, y_subs] = get_circle_indices(circ_radius, circ_x_center, circ_y_center)

    persistent circle_lookup_table;

    % Make sure the table's already been generated; if not, generate it.
    if (isempty(circle_lookup_table))
        circle_lookup_table = generate_circles(100); %upper bound circ size
    end

    % Get the right circle from the struct, and center it at the requested center
    x_subs = circle_lookup_table(circ_radius).x_coords + circ_x_center;
    y_subs = circle_lookup_table(circ_radius).y_coords + circ_y_center;

end
```

However, it turns out this is SLOW!
Over 200,000 function calls, MATLAB spent on average 9 microseconds each call just to establish that the persistent variable exists! (Not the isEmpty() call, but the actual variable declaration). This is according to MATLAB's built-in profiler.

This added back most of the time gained from implementing the lookup table.

I also tried implementing it as a global variable (similar time to check if the variable is declared) or passing it in as a variable (made the function call much more expensive).

So, my question is this:

**How do I provide fast access inside a function to runtime-constant data?**

I look forward to some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT runtime-constant data, since your function has the ability of generating the table. So your main problem is to discard this instruction from the function. Before all the calls of this critical function, make sure that this array is generated elsewhere outside the function.

However, there is a nice trick I've read from Matlab's files, and more specifically `bwmorph`. For each functionality of this particuliar function which requires a LUTs, they have created a function which returns the LUT itself (the LUT is written explicitely in the file). They also add an instruction `coder.inline('always')` to ensure that this function will be inlined. It seems to be quite efficient!

Comment: Thanks for the response! What version of MATLAB are you using? In my (student license) R2012a, I cannot find this example in my copy of bwmorph!

Also, it sounds like they would have to regenerate the LUT on each function call - I want the same LUT to persist through each function call without being regenerated.

Comment: @Glenn Do you have the Image Processing Toolbox? The file itself can be accessed if you type `bwmorph` in the command window, then select it and press `Ctrl+D`. In the file, the interesting function is `images.internal.algbwmorph`. Press again `Ctrl+D` and you are in the file which calls the luts, so you can make your choice :)

Comment: @Glenn Concerning the generation of the LUTs, I think that due to the inlining instruction, the LUT may not be regenerated each time... but I don't have found any proof of that.

Comment: That doesn't really follow my understanding of function inlining in normal cases, but I'll have to go give it a shot. I also looked through my copy of bwmorph (yes, i have the 2012a toolbox), and I don't see the reference to coder.inline or to images.internal.algbwmorph.

Comment: Also, from the MATLAB documentation for coder.inline(), it looks as though it is just an instruction to the MATLAB coder (which I am not using) to inline the function in generated code, not during interpreted runs.

Comment: @Glenn I have Matlab version 2013b, so it seems quite new. As you pointed out, it is used for generated code, so what's the point of placing that here? Maybe it acts as an hint for the interpreter too? Really don't know, sorry. I just want to point out this thing, as I've seen that recently, and I think that programmers at Matlab do not put spurious code in their releases ... :)